# asp.net remove apostrophe from parameterized query

Tags: asp.net, parameterized-query

```
MySqlParameter[] sqlParams = new MySqlParameter[] 
    { new MySqlParameter { ParameterName = "@ParameterValue", Value = someValue} };
```

actual value of someValue is (`'1', '2', '3', '4'`)

but when it goes through parameterized query the value turns to `'('1\',\'2\',\'3\',\'4\')'`

How can I remove `'\'` or prevent parameterized query from producing `'\'`?

Comment: Do you mean that `someValue` is an array of characters? You haven't given the SqlDbType in your parameter constructor, so we can't tell what you intend it to be from looking at it.

Comment: It's a string  ('1', '2', '3', '4')